# Is this a singular point? And why?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this ODE

$$x'' + \frac{2}{t} x' + x = 0$$
by series expansion around $t_0=0.$

I know it's very simple, but I'm kind of not sure whether this is a singular point or an ordinary one. Several things confuse me.

First of all, is the point considered singular only if it's a zero of the leading term?

And also, when I try solving it as an ordinary point, assuming $$x(t)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty c_k t^k, $$
I conclude that all the odd terms in the recurrent relation vanish, so I get only one solution, that can't be right...

I'm not quite comfortable with these concepts because I don't really get the motivation for some definitions, such as the singular point, so I would appreciate a clear and meaningful explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point $t=0$ is a regular singular point because the coefficient of $x'$ has an isolated singularity at $t=0$. The coefficient of $\frac{1}{t^{2}}$ multiplying $x(t)$ is $0$, which is probably causing some confusion. So the indicial equation is obtained by substituting $x(t)=t^{\rho}$ into
$$
            x''+\frac{1}{t}x'=0 \implies \rho(\rho-1)+\rho=0\implies \rho=0.
$$
So you're guaranteed one series solution $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}t^{n+\rho}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}t^{n}$, but the other solution requires a $\ln x$ term because $\rho=0$ is a double root of the indicial equation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe it is a singular point and the solution is in terms of the Bessel functions of the first and second type, e.g.

$$ x(t)=t^{-1/2}[C_{1} J_{1}(2t^{1/2})+ C_{2} Y_{1}(2t^{1/2})]. $$

Hope this helps some.

Cheers,

Paul Safier

Comment: Are you sure it's a singular point, can you explain why?
I also believe it is, but I want to know x)

Comment: To use the terminology from singularity discussions in Bessel's equation, the coefficient function $p_{1}(t)=2/t$ is not analytic at $t=0$ and is thus there is a regular singularity at that point, $t=0$.

Comment: A series solution at a non-singular point, is non-singular (i.e. analytic).  So the $t^{1/2}$ could not be there.